# how can I export this output data into Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I want to export output data into excel, what can we implement into this code below?
Note: ",".join method is welcome for output.

```
import json

with open("example.json", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    jsondata = json.load(f)

for league in jsondata["results"][0]["Elems"]:
    for matches in league["Elems"]:
        if "Friendly" in matches["ligName"]:
            continue
        print(matches["ligName"],matches["date"],matches["teamnames"],matches["score"][0])
```

Comment: Well, you already have pandas, openpyxl and xlsxwriter in your tags, and you're not showing any attempt to use any of them..?

Comment: First of all, what is the output you are referring to?  Is it the last print statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('data.json')

df.to_excel('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: there is no data.json in my code.

Comment: @kolasinac use `example.json` instead of it.